# background-position

Tags: html, css, forms, input, textbox

Im trying to use an image in textbox like so (## being the image):

```
 ---------------------
|                  ## |
 ---------------------
```

I have managed to somewhat with the following:

```
input.loading {
    background: url(/images/loader.gif) no-repeat right;
}
```

However it comes out like so:

```
 ---------------------
|                   ##|
 ---------------------
```

What I need to do is add some padding to the right side but I am lost as to how I can accomplish this.

Comment: you could use a `margin-right:10px;` in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `right` to `98%` or so.  (`right` is just short hand for `100%`)

http://jsfiddle.net/gsUBL/

EDIT:
I don't know why jsfiddle is having an issue with displaying it (in chrome at least).  Clicking run shows it working.

Answer (score 2):

you could use a `margin-right:10px;` in your css

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead. It will solve your problem.

```
background-position:10px 200px;
```

[See this example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position&preval=10px%20200px) and play around :)

Comment: please don't link to w3schools :) [they have a few problems](http://w3fools.com) and it is not advised to use them as a resource.  Try MDN or another reputable site.

Comment: @Joseph Well, I'll bear in mind that. However, I won't remove the link this time since the example they provide is useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the positioning of `no-repeat right;` to a percentage that you want as `right` is just an easier way to to mark fully to the right or `100%`. 
Positioning by pixels might cause unwanted horizontal scroll bars or even overlapping if their computers have a different display resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways. If the input box is never going to change width then put the exact pixel amount you want in the CSS instead of "right" `background: url(/images/loader.gif) no-repeat 200px;`. I'd recommend rather doing exactly what you're doing `background: url(/images/loader.gif) no-repeat right;` and instead adding `padding-right: 20px;` (or however much you need) to the input box.